# Generic variable declaration with wildChar vs without wildChar

Tags: java, generics

```
interface Shape { }
class Circle implements Shape { }

class ShapeContainer<T extends Shape> {
    T sh;
    public ShapeContainer(T newInstance) {
        sh = newInstance;
    }
    ...
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        ShapeContainer<Shape> A = new ShapeContainer(new Circle());
        ShapeContainer<? extends Shape> B = new ShapeContainer(new Circle());
    }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of declaring the variable as  `ShapeContainer<Shape> A` vs `ShapeContainer<? extends Shape> B`

What condition should each one be preferred?

Comment: The duplicate anwers talk about the genrics in the method input params. This question is about variable declaration of handling of the output

Comment: Since Generics are class invariant, the difference will occur in a method like this:
```public List<? super E> union(List<? extends E> l1, List<? extends E> l2) { 
Iterator<? extends E> iterator = l1.iterator(); //will compile fine
Iterator<E> iterator = l2.iterator();// wont compile because list l2 is collection of subtypes of E and iterator should also be like that.. ````
For eg if you create two lists with List<Rectangle> and List<Circle> and you want to make union of those two and store in List<Shapes> it should be possible with the function specified above. Hope this helps

Comment: Gist is if you are expecting subtype of Elements we should use - <? extends E>

Comment: @user1673567 that make sense for input variable of a method. My question is about output variable declaration

Comment: If you see the output variable here which I used to depict the difference is - Iterator<? extends E> iterator  and Iterator<E>.. let me know if I am still not clear